# how to run vcvarsall.bat from python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I know how to use Popen to run one .bat file. In this case I need to first run vcvarsall.bat and initialize compiler tools, and then in the same environment run a third part .bat that will actually use compiler tools. Whats the best way of doing this?

thanks!

Comment: The best way would be to create a another "driver" batch file that first `call`s vcvarsall.bat then uses the compiler tool from within the environment the former sets up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
subprocess.Popen('"vcvarsall.bat" x86&&"invoke_compiler.bat"', shell=True)
```

Comment: I think i may have more than one problem and I'm just realizing. I can run vcvarsall.bat no problem from cmd. I can run Popen(vcvarsall.bat, shell=True) from a python interpreter in command, but when i try and run the same Popen command while unittesting it says it can't find vcvarsall.bat. Am i missing a setting somewhere?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem must be with eclipse seeing the environment variables. Thanks so much for you're answer.

Comment: We use a more elaborate version on our build server. See 'get_vsvars_environment' here: https://github.com/openhome/ohdevtools/blob/master/ci_build.py#L28 It looks at the VS100COMNTOOLS/VS110COMNTOOLS environment variable to find the vsvarsall.bat file, and a one-line Python script to dump out the environment to be read back into the parent Python process.